# NHibernateException:Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, oracle10g

I have an WPF application based on NHibernate => oracle10g XE. 
I'm getting error msg mentioned in title when I'm trying to connect from remote computer (Windows 7).

Of course I've installed ODAC (ODAC112030Xcopy_x64), it's installed in GAC and in machine.config as well, I also added the Oracle.DataAccess to bin folder.

I've already read [this article](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/unable-to-find-requested-net-framework.html) but unfortunatelly it didn't help.

The most interesting issue is, I've tested my app on many machines, and on those which have VS2010 installed everything works perfectly, connection is established and so on.

What am I missing ? what's more need to be installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `Fluent` configuration? I had the same problem when using Framework 4.0. To solve it, I changed the session configuration. Instead of using:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
```

Try:

```
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.OracleDataClientConfiguration.Oracle10
```

The first one uses the namespace `System.Data.OracleClient`, the second one uses the `Oracle.DataAccess`.

I'm using Oracle Client 11g R2, ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0), on 32 bits and 64 bits windows 7.